# Discord bot images

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

My cat, Tris, has basically became a meme in my server, so I decided to add her as a command.

```
@client.command()
async def Tris(ctx):
    responses = [ 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/641480658107236352/676150710236217351/image1.jpg',
                'https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/641480658107236352/676150710236217351/image1.jpg',
                'https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/641480658107236352/676150710815162368/image2.jpg',
                'https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/641480658107236352/676150711590977567/image3.jpg']
    await ctx.send(f'{random.choices(responses)}')
```

But not only will the images not show, but the link also shows up weird.
Is there a better way to do this? Especially if there is an easier way of doing it.
Or a way to fix this?
I am a first-time programmer so I have no idea what I am doing.

Comment: I don't see what's wrong with this, how is the link "weird"? All of those links are valid for me and do show up on discord.

Comment: For me they show up with ['link'] instead of just the link itself.

Comment: Oh sorry didn't see that. What you want is to use `choice` not `choices` as the first is for one thing and the latter is for returning choice/s as list.

Comment: That fixed the problem! Thank you so much!